# Capturing CTRL+Key In KeyPressEvent in PyQGIS QgsMaptool

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, events

I created a Line with help of `QgsMapTool` and I'm able to capture the single key in `keyPressEvent` like this:

```py
class buildingEditTool(QgsMapToolEdit):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            ''' Do Something'''
```

then for a key combination I tried

```py
class buildingEditTool(QgsMapToolEdit):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        
        if event.matchs(QKeySequence(ctrl+k)):
            ''' Do Something'''
```

but it did not work.

How do I capture combination keys in `keyPressEvent`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QKeyEvent` has a method `modifiers()`. You should use it.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):

    if event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_R:
            print("Ctrl + R")
```